# What is the appropriate data structure for insertion sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I revisited insertion sort algorithm and noticed something funny.

One obviously shouldn't use an array with this sort, as upon insertion, one will have to shift all subsequent elements **O(n^2 log(n))**. However a linked list is also not good here, since we preferably find the right placement using binary search, which isn't possible for a simple linked list (so we end up with **O(n^2)**).

Which makes me wonder: what is a data structure on which this sorting algorithm provides its premise of **O(nlog(n))** complexity?

Comment: Shifting elements is not necessarily a heavy operation if elements are placed consecutively so I would opt for the array solution.

Comment: Where did you read that insertion sort has O(n log n) time complexity? It is a classic O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: Using binary search to find the insertion spot is not necessarily the right solution. Experimental data doesn't show a clear preference. In most places where insertion sort is used (small arrays, or small subarrays in high-performance sorts), linear search outperforms binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a gapped array and a binary search to figure out where to insert things, then with high probability your sort will be `O(n log(n))`.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_sort for details.

However this is not as efficient as a wide variety of other sorts that are widely implemented.  So this knowledge is only of theoretical interest.

Answer (score 2):

From where did you get the premise of **O(n log n)**?  [Wikipedia disagrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), as does my own experience.  The premises of the insertion sort include components that are **O(n)** for each of the `n` elements.

Also, I believe that your claim of **O(n^2 log n)** is incorrect.  The binary search is *log n*, and the ensuing "move sideways" is *n*, but these two steps are in succession, not nested.  The result is *n + log n*, not a multiplication.  The result is the expected **O(n^2)**.

Answer (score 1):

Insertion sort is defined over array or list, if you use some other data structure, then it will be another algorithm.

Of course if you use a BST, insertion and search would be O(log(n)) and your overall complexity would be O(n.log(n)) on the average (remind that it will be O(n^2) in the worst), but this will be no more an insertion sort but a **tree sort**. If you use an AVL tree, then you get the O(n.log(n)) worst case complexity.

Answer (score 0):

In insertion sort the best case scenario is when the sequence is already sorted and that takes Linear time and in the worst case takes **O(n^2)** time. I do not know how you got the logarithmic part in the complexity.